# Why does using the npm command give the error?

Tags: npm, npm-install

When I run the command `npm -v` it gives me this error. Also running any command starting with npm gives this error. What can I do to fix it? I have attached the error message below. Thank you.

````
OpenSSL configuration error:
54330000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
54330000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
54330000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
OpenSSL configuration error:
C8330000:error:80000002:system library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
C8330000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
C8330000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:```
````